# HDIV : ajax call for uploading file not working

Tags: ajax, struts-1, multipart, hdiv

We are using HDIV to protect our web application from the csrf attacks.
Recently we try to upload file (multipart) using ajax call but it seems not working.
the form file param is null in the form.

Plus, we have the follwing message:

```
Unable to find 'saveDir' property setting. Defaulting to javax.servlet.context.tempdir [org.hdiv.config.multipart.AbstractMultipartConfig] [getRepositoryPath() 124]
```

Any idea how to fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: Even without ajax, it's still not working. The param is null.

Answer (score 2):

Have you configured *multipartresolver* bean? Can you review your Spring's configuration and confirm that you are using a bean of   *org.hdiv.web.multipart.HdivCommonsMultipartResolver* class?

[image: HDIV REference Documentation]

Gorka | HDIV Team

Comment: Our application is built on struts 1 framework. We don't use Spring MVC or may be you make reference to something else.

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv-struts-examples/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/upload/struts-config.xml) the configuration (controller) that you have to add to your Struts configuration file. I hope this help you.